# Pass instance attributes to another object in Python

Tags: python

I would like to wrap different objects inside a class. And I would also like the the class to have the same attributes as the object that it's wrapping, plus some additional attributes.

```
class City:     
    def __init__(self, inhabitants, mayor):         
        self.inhabitants = inhabitants         
        self.mayor = mayor          

class Country:     
    def __init__(self, inhabitants, president):
        self.inhabitants = inhabitants
        self.president = president

class Wrapper:
    def __init__(self, object):
        ...
        self.new_attr = 'attr'

city = City(100_000, 'M')
country = Country(10_000_000, 'P')

city_wrapper = Wrapper(city)
country_wrapper = Wrapper(country)
```

I would like the wrapper to be as agnostic as possible to the nature of the object it is wrapping.

As a solution I though I could assign the wrapped object's `__dict__` to the wrapper `__dict__`:

```
class Wrapper:
    def __init__(self, object):
        self.__dict__ = object.__dict__
        self.new_attr = 'attr'
```

Are there any drawbacks to this solution?

Comment: `__init__`, not `_init_`.

Comment: Being agnostic, there's no guarantee that `self.new_attr = 'attr'` doesn't overwrite an existing attribute, rather than creating a new one.

Comment: Side note: don't use `object` as a variable name since it is already used for the name of the primordial class.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice Practically speaking, though, how often do you actually need to refer to `object`? Shadowing the built-in here is only a problem if you planned on using the built-in name in your local scope; it doesn't affect any other functions that might use the built-in in *their* local scope.

Comment: @chepner Yes, at the end of the day, it's probably not a big deal, especially as you say this is in a local scope. I generally avoid shadowing built-in names to avoid the possibility of issues now or in the future.

Answer (score 0):

I am sure you expected this, but: It depends.

What is a drawback depends on what you want to do with instances of that wrapper class.

In your example already, you are assigning a value to `new_attr` inside the `Wrapper.__init__`. Obviously, if the wrapped object has an attribute with that name, that would be overwritten in the wrapper at this moment.

Now, whether or not that is problem for you, is up to you.

An additional problem with the `__dict__` copying approach is that static type checkers will be unable to recognize **any** of the attributes passed along this way. Is that important? Only you know that.

Since I don't know how you want to *use* this wrapper, I can only give general suggestions. I see no reason not to simply use composition for example. Why not simply like this?

```py
class Wrapper:
    def __init__(self, obj):
        self.obj = obj
        self.new_attr = 'attr'
```

I don't see how it could be any more agnostic than that. Attribute access to the wrapped object works just the same: `wrapped.obj.attr`

Comment: Being agnostic, this is probably a good solution, because the wrapper class wouldn't possibly override any attribute of the wrapped object.